# Using Mat Option Group in Reactive Forms

Tags: angular-material

I am trying to implement a radio button group in a form. This is how I did it:

**.ts**

```
yesNo: any = [
    'Yes',
    'No'
];
createForm() {
    this.createPropertyForm = this.fb.group({  
        latepymtpen: [null],
});
ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
}
```

**.html**

```
<mat-form-field class="occupy-half-wmargin">
    <mat-radio-group formControlName="latepymtpen">
        <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let yn of yesNo" [value]="yn">
            {{yn}}
        </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
</mat-form-field>
```

When I run it, I get this error:
`ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.`

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

MatFormField is for components like MatInput, MatSelect, and others which implement the MatFormFieldControl interface. MatRadioGroup is not one of them. In other words, you can't use a MatRadioGroup inside a MatFormField the way you have.

Comment: Oh I see.. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll just vote up cause I didn't get a solution. By the way, I just used a select box.